# Yii2 Migrations command not recognizing

Tags: database, yii2, migration

I want to run my new migration, before that I checked for new migration using "PHP Yii migrate" command.
It gives me

> ...\common\config\params.php on line 13 Error: Unknown command
>   "migration".

***My params file :***

```
$fullUrl = 'http'.(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'':'s').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (strpos($fullUrl,'/frontend') !== false) {
    $webUrl = explode('/frontend', $fullUrl);
    $value = $webUrl[0].'/frontend/web';
} else if (strpos($fullUrl,'/backend') !== false) {
    $webUrl = explode('/backend', $fullUrl);
    $value = $webUrl[0].'/backend/web';
} else {
    $value = 'http'.(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'':'s').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}

$advertisementUrl = str_replace('admin.', '', $value);

return [
    'adminEmail' => 'test@test.com',
    'supportEmail' => 'support@test.com',
    'advertisement' => $advertisementUrl,
    'user.passwordResetTokenExpire' => 3600,
    'currentWebsiteUrl' => $value,
    'hash' => 'cba',
    'newsfeedOffset' => 20
];
```

Comment: add the complete error string or paste the image? and there is no command with the name `migration` if you are on terminal go to the project root and typ `./yii migrate` to run the migration `./yii migrate/create createProductsTable` to create new migration for `product` table

Comment: Thanks  Muhammad Omer Aslam my command was wrong .

Comment: you are welcome.

Comment: hey can you mark the answer as correct by clicking on the `✔` icon with the answer

Answer (score 1):

To run the migrations go to the root directory of your project and run the command

```
./yii migrate
```

and to create a migration you should

```
./yii migrate/create myMigrationName
```